# Javascript not loaded in test.html from index.html via href://test.html

Tags: javascript, html, google-app-engine

As a newby using javascript, I am running through the code sample for Appengine (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/clients/js/add_post).  I added a hyper link to a new html page (test.html).  However, when I test the test.html.  The javascript does not work.  I think it is not loaded.  Need some direction.  Thanks in advance.

---

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Endpoints!</title>
    <script async src="/js/base.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 40px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }
        blockquote {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            border-left-color: #bbb;
        }
        form {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        form label {
          width: 90px;
          display: inline-block;
        }
        .form-signin input[type="text"] {
            font-size: 16px;
            height: auto;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            padding: 7px 9px;
        }
        .row {
            margin-left: 0px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="testLinks">
    <a href="test.html">test Page</a>
</div>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="brand" href="#">Hello Endpoints!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Endpoints!</title>
    <script async src="/js/base.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 40px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }
        blockquote {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            border-left-color: #bbb;
        }
        form {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        form label {
          width: 90px;
          display: inline-block;
        }
        .form-signin input[type="text"] {
            font-size: 16px;
            height: auto;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            padding: 7px 9px;
        }
        .row {
            margin-left: 0px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="brand" href="#">Hello Endpoints!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

base.js:

```
/**
 * @fileoverview
 * Provides methods for the Hello Endpoints sample UI and interaction with the
 * Hello Endpoints API.
 */

/** google global namespace for Google projects. */
var google = google || {};

/** appengine namespace for Google Developer Relations projects. */
google.appengine = google.appengine || {};

/** samples namespace for App Engine sample code. */
google.appengine.samples = google.appengine.samples || {};

/** hello namespace for this sample. */
google.appengine.samples.hello = google.appengine.samples.hello || {};

/**
 * Prints a greeting to the greeting log.
 * param {Object} greeting Greeting to print.
 */
google.appengine.samples.hello.print = function(greeting) {
  var element = document.createElement('div');
  element.classList.add('row');
  element.innerHTML = greeting.message;
  document.querySelector('#outputLog').appendChild(element);
};

/**
 * Gets a numbered greeting via the API.
 * @param {string} id ID of the greeting.
 */
google.appengine.samples.hello.getGreeting = function(id) {
  gapi.client.helloworld.greetings.getGreeting({'id': id}).execute(
      function(resp) {
        if (!resp.code) {
          google.appengine.samples.hello.print(resp);
        }
      });
};

/**
 * Lists greetings via the API.
 */
google.appengine.samples.hello.listGreeting = function() {
  gapi.client.helloworld.greetings.listGreeting().execute(
      function(resp) {
        if (!resp.code) {
          resp.items = resp.items || [];
          for (var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
            google.appengine.samples.hello.print(resp.items[i]);
          }
        }
      });
};

/**
 * Enables the button callbacks in the UI.
 */
google.appengine.samples.hello.enableButtons = function() {
  var getGreeting = document.querySelector('#getGreeting');
  getGreeting.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    google.appengine.samples.hello.getGreeting(
        document.querySelector('#id').value);
  });

  var listGreeting = document.querySelector('#listGreeting');
  listGreeting.addEventListener('click',
      google.appengine.samples.hello.listGreeting);

};
/**
 * Initializes the application.
 * @param {string} apiRoot Root of the API's path.
 */
google.appengine.samples.hello.init = function(apiRoot) {
  // Loads the OAuth and helloworld APIs asynchronously, and triggers login
  // when they have completed.
  var apisToLoad;
  var callback = function() {
    if (--apisToLoad == 0) {
      google.appengine.samples.hello.enableButtons();
    }
  }

  apisToLoad = 1; // must match number of calls to gapi.client.load()
  gapi.client.load('helloworld', 'v1', callback, apiRoot);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You must atleast add js in HTML header like,

index.html

```
 <html>
    <head>
     <script src="myscripts.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body></body>
    </html>
```

like Javascript file and html file should be like in this folder structure

> testFolder/js/base.js
>
> testFolder/index.html

Comment: It is in the test.html file line (5):   (<script async src="/js/base.js"></script>), I also tried, (<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/problem.js"></script>). Nether one work.

Comment: This is the the java file to bound the javascript and .htnl together:

Comment: @wasabi Answer modified and explained how to folder structure required.

Comment: I am using the folder structure that came with the example.:

Comment: I am using the folder structure that came with the example.: (src/main/webapp/js/base.js) and the html files are int he same folder (src/main/webapp/index,html and (src/main/webapp/test.html).  I am assuming that mvn will pick up all the html files because they are in the same directory.  They both reference the same javascript base.js.  Could it have anything to do with the namespace?

Comment: @wasabi for Java or other language it dependents on the configuration how you running the page.

Comment: Can you check in console what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the return null from the html page.  I had multiple DOM request for element in the test.js file.  This wa sdue to copying the .js from another .js.  In summary, if you have any DOM request, it must have a corresponding tag in teh html file.  If not, it will return a null.  If you don't care, it fine.  But, in my case, I am expecting a valid return.  This, it throws an exception.

p.s. Also be careful of ordering.  If you have mix DOM request.  It could also cause a problem during debugging.